# call R function with parameter from cmd

Tags: r, function, cmd, call

I have file `a.R` with one function:

```
  big_name<-function(name){
    big_name<-toupper(toString(name))
    return(big_name)
  }
```

How can I call this function from cmd(command prompt or shell) with parameter for example `"John"`, without R opening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do : `R -e "source('./big_name.R'); big_name('test')"`
If you added R in your system path.